# Using Randoop to automatically generate Junit classes for Spring mvc controller .

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, randoop

I have a spring mvc web application and I want to automatically generate the junit class for each request handling method defined in my controller.How to use Randoop to generate Junit class that mocks my repository and service class.
I need at least the junit skelton for my controller.

Answer (score 0):

Randoop does not generate mocks.  You should create any needed mocks.  Then, you can use Randoop to generate JUnit tests.